# Modify a date object to another format

Tags: java, date, datetime, date-formatting

I downloaded date information from an API which is in the format of (Java)

```
day month monthnumber hour:minute:second EST year
```

how can I format this into just

```
month monthnumber year
```

Comment: Have you heard of `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/text/java-dateformat-example/

Comment: I'm sure this question has been answered, many times here before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to first parse the string to a `java.util.Date`, and then format it to the format you want:

```
String orig = "Thu Feb 19 19:40:12 EST 2015";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date date = parser.parse(orig);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
String formatted = formatter.format(date);
```

Comment: this worked perfectly thanks. I just had to change ("MMM dd YYYY") to ("MMM dd yyyy") the other way causes an error